Visual Studio Code launched from WSL shows large number of changes while there are no actual changes
I am trying to move development of our Laravel apps from Windows to WSL, have encountered an issue related to git.
If I launch Visual Studio Code from within WSL by entering the following command:
code .

Visual Studio Code will show a large number of files have been changed, even the repo is fresh git clone.

If type the following command under WSL:
git status

Then only those files that have actually been changed are listed in console output.

I tried to set git to ignore file permission as mentioned in this post, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.
Could someone advise what I am missing here? VS Code + WSL otherwise seems like a perfect development setup.

The issue seems to be caused by some sort of cache mechanism utilized by git and/or VS Code. After applying the the following settings on WSL as suggested by another thread:
git config core.filemode false  

It doesn't take effect immediately. But once I actually committed some changes in that repo then all of changes that were falsely listed just disappeared.I assume restarting the WSL instance can also fix the problem.
Such behavior seems like particular to WSL. The other day, after changing file permission of /var/www/ folder on WSL, I had to restart the WSL instance before the changed permission to actually take effect.
